# Why after migration from vSphere to Google Cloud caused slow upload limit to 0.60MBPS using CloudEndure?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-compute-engine, vsphere

I recently migrated a VM from vSphere vmware to Google Cloud Compute Instance.

I used CloudEndure, and everything worked fine, the VM is identical. But there is one problem. The upload is super slow, under 1mbps (0.65mbps), while the download is just super fast 300-900 mbps.

I tried twice migration changed vNic, changed zone region, everything but no luck. The funny thing is I put a temporary VM provided by GCP to connect rdp in the same subnet, and that temp-VM works fine.

Did you have this experience ?

Appreciate your suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any coding involve in the process, unless its coding problem you might not be answered

Answer (score 0):

To change your MTU setting in Windows Server 2003 or 2008 use the following steps:

Open regedit as an administrator account on the server in question.
Navigate to HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces[Choose the interface in question] (Do this by checking the correct IP address is in the settings under this key for the adapter you are configuring)
Once you are in the correct key for your interface, right-click and select new DWORD value (32 bit).
Call it MTU
Give this a decimal value equal to the setting 1460 (measured in bytes).